# Scala tree structure and inserting side effects via implicit parameters

Tags: scala, implicit

I have a simple tree of `Node`s, each of which has an `apply` method that takes a given `State` and returns a new `State` and the next `Node` in the tree.

```
trait Node[SE <: SideEffect] {
  def apply(state: State)(implicit sideEffect: SE): (State, Node[_])
}
```

As you can see, I'd like to be able to also pass in specific types of side effects when I finally apply the function.

For individual nodes this works just fine. However, when I want to recursively descend the tree it seems to fall apart. For instance, without side effects the following code works:

```
def execute(state: State, node: Node): (State, Node) = node(state) match {
  case (result, end: End) => (result, end)
  case (result, continue) => execute(result, continue)
}
```

However, if try something similar taking an implicit side effects, it doesn't work:

```
def execute[SE <: SideEffect](state: State, node: Node[SE])(implicit sideEffect: SE): (State, Node[_]) = {
  node(state) match {
    case (result, end: End) => (result, end)
    case (result, continue) => execute(result, continue)
  }
}

<console>:20: error: inferred type arguments [_0] do not conform to method execute's type parameter bounds [SE <: SideEffect]
             case (result, continue) => execute(result, continue)
                                        ^
<console>:20: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Node[_0] where type _0
 required: Node[SE]
             case (result, continue) => execute(result, continue)
                                                        ^
<console>:20: error: could not find implicit value for parameter sideEffect: SE
             case (result, continue) => execute(result, continue)
                                               ^
```

I guess the fundamental problem is that each call to `execute` would have to already have in scope all the implicits for all subsequent calls to `execute`.

Given this, is there any way to easily pass in side effects later? I'd like to be able to define the tree of `Nodes` in one place and then walk the tree in another place with a specified set of side effects.

Comment: Have you tried to have apply return `(State, Node[SE])` instead of `(State, Node[_])`?

Comment: That would then require the second Node to have the same side effect type as the first one, no?

Comment: Yes. What you cannot do is some run-time lookup of the actual type of node and then expect the compiler to somehow retroactively lookup an implicit param for that…

Comment: Maybe you could try making it work with explicitly passed parameters and then see how to later replaced some of them with implicits? From what you've showed, I'm confused about your data structure because it seems that the shape of the tree depends on the initial state.

Comment: Yes, you're correct that the shape depends on the initial state in the design that I describe. Ultimately I think what I wanted to do is not (easily?) possible.